# iOS UiCollectionView - reloadData using custom UiCollectionViewLayout

Tags: ios, json, uicollectionview, reloaddata, uicollectionviewlayout

I'm trying to use a custom UiCollectionViewLayout but I have a little problem. 
In my project I want to load some JSON information and present it in a UICollectionView. I need to load the information from WEB and then (when everything is loaded) I need to reload my Collection View.
If I use the `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` everything works great. However, when I try to use my own layout, the `reloadData` doesn't work properly and nothing happens.

I'm reloading the data with an async task:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ 

            [self.newsCollectionView reloadData];

        });
```

Thanks

Comment: Please show more code in cellForItemAtIndexPath and your custom layout!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for `invalidateLayout`, which causes `prepareLayout`, `collectionViewContentSize`, `layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:`etc to be called.

Comment: I swear invalidateLayout does not cause prepareLayout (etc) to be called ... I've tried 100 times.  it's sick.